# Append data to config file on linux

Tags: python, linux, config, configparser

I would like to append data to my `file.config`. Also I'm using linux, which will request permissions to any kind of configuration to the file. In the terminal I can write `sudo nano file.config` and make the changes.

Expectation: my file.cofig looks like this

```py
#
#info ...
#
#
[Section]
#info
I want to append data right here to the end of the file
```

I tried using `configparser` module:

```py
configparser = configparser.ConfigParser()   
configparser['Section'] = {'data':'123'}
configFilePath = '/etc/file.conf'

with open(configFilePath, 'a') as file_conf:
  configparser.write(file_conf)
```

This will add information as a dictionary, instead as the regular file.txt

```py
#
#info ...
#
#
[Section]
#info
[Section]
data = 123
```

*As requested in the comments: sudo python3 file.py was requiered (visual studio was not in su mode)*

Comment: Everything in `/etc` is root-write-only by default. You need to run your script in administrative mode (`sudo python file.py`) .

Comment: It worked, I thought I was on su on visual studio, but I was wrong. How I can write simple information to the end though?`

Comment: Because `configparser['ProxyList'] = #'DATA I WOULD LIKE TO APPEND'` will create this section, I just want to add info to the end as the regular append on a txt file

Comment: No idea, never used that lib. `open(configFilePath, 'a') as fh: fh.write('ProxyList something something\n')` would be my uneducated answer to this :)

Comment: OK, I'll try and I will update the question

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html.  See add_section, set, get, ...